# Checking route parameters are a specific value?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

My route:

```
Route::get('/{type?}/{filter?}', [IndexController::class, 'index']);
```

Is there a way, like form requests, where I can check that `$type` and `$filter` are specific values, for example `$filter` is equal to `new` or perhaps `trending`?

I've considered just specifying the finite number of options as routes themselves:

```
Route::get('/books/new', [IndexController::class, 'index']);
```

But I am then unable to get these params in the controller. Please note, I do not wish to have separate controllers for each `$type`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can constrain the route parameter to a regular expression, as explained [in the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints).

```php
Route::get('/{type?}/{filter?}', [IndexController::class, 'index'])
    ->where(['filter' => '^(new|trending)$']);
```

But I think it would make more sense to keep this logic centralised in your controller:

```php
public function index(string $type, string $filter)
{
    switch ($type) {
        case "books":
            // do something
            break;
        case "films":
            // do something
            break;
        default:
            abort(404);
    }
}
```